# Why has the green accepted answer indicator become darker on all the sites?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design, accepted-answer

I just noticed this change recently; the green accepted answer indicator has become darker (i.e., from **47%** [lightness](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_color_hsl_lightness) to **31%**) on all the sites:

> [image] [image]

Previous design for comparison:

> [image] [image]

Was this intended?

Comment: Looks like an [accessibility change](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/419586/6083675). It's hard for some people to see light text on a lightish background. If you can find the hex for the colors you can [check online for contrast](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/).

Comment: @Laurel, I see.. It looks weird because it doesn’t match the color of the check mark next to answers (unless that’s going to be changed as well).

Comment: They probably should make the colors match, though that's just an aesthetic thing. (The checkmark is big enough to easily see, I believe.)

Comment: A change to the checkmark is coming soon, both will have the same green.

Comment: The screenshot could benefit from a frame.

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum not really, we can't expect people to spend time on such things. In the past quote formatting used to be enough but SE changed that so we lost that "feature".

Comment: "*Was this intended?*" - Of course it was, all the design changes in the last 2 years or so have been done like this. SE changes it _because reasons_ (usually something nobody asked for, while things that were asked are not made), ignores community feedback (which means they won't revert it, no matter how much we complain) and life goes on, until the next awful change occurs...

Answer (score -4, accepted):

This change was intentional and part of our [accessibility updates](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419586/announcing-design-accessibility-updates-on-so). For the curious, here's the change in our design system Stacks: https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/pull/1086

We'll have additional changes to ensure consistency for the "success"/"accepted"/"answer" colors coming soon and more details about the specific color changes. Thanks for looking out and for your patience while we make accessibility improvements.

Comment: This just looks horrible. It's way too dark. All the other colours on the page are far lighter, this just falls completely out of line, and the page should feel "light", these dark colours are just a bit depressing. Please revert!

Comment: This update [messes with site theme colors for watched questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/381863/watched-question-titles-are-changed-to-blue-on-themed-sites).

Comment: It's too dark. It doesn't look green anymore, it just looks dark/black. Surely you can get adequate contrast without going *this* dark. If not, try inverting the color scheme so that it's light green with dark text? **This change actively interferes with accessibility/usability because I can no longer scan the page and easily find all of the answered questions.** There are no longer distinct "badges", it's just dark stuff that blends in with other dark text. I kind of find this "accessibility" claim hard to follow when I see the "Staff" and "Mod" badges right here on this page that are light.

Comment: As someone with deuteranopia (red-green colorblindness) the new color looks somewhat red to me. Previously it was something I recognized as green. Maybe back off on the "deepness"/"darkness" of the green a bit?

Comment: Have you guys considered moving the high-contrast stuff to a separate high-contrast theme? This would make everyone happy: the users get to keep the colors they're used to, and those who need the contrast can have it.

Comment: Wait, we *already have* a high-contrast theme! Why are those changes not limited to it?

Comment: The change adheres to WCAG 2.1 color contrast guidelines. We will be sharing some details about specific color changes in the near future as Dan mentioned.

Comment: I don't fully understand what's the end goal here. "Adhere to WCAG 2.1" is not a meaningful end goal, it's a tool. "Improving accessibility" can be a goal, but then I don't entirely understand why not hide accesibility features behind a special setting (which already exists, so you don't need to get developers involved), given that the users seemed to be content with the existing coloring, and fussy about any changes (first the vote buttons, then this).

Comment: I put together my concerns, and came up with an alternate implementation: [Give us back the lightgreen box for accepted answers. It can be accessible too!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/381864/give-us-back-the-lightgreen-box-for-accepted-answers-it-can-be-accessible-too)

Comment: @Luuklag "you better get some designers on board" Why buy the cow when you can get the milk for free? I fear SE is content to rely on the community to iron out testing and design. It's been a few hours and they've already got several issues reported and your excellent design proposal.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov I'm sure they employ designers, but usually these kind of projects are just playing with stuff by devs, until it matches a certain criteria. I wouldn't revert my change in the first few hours either, I'd wait a couple of days to receive feedback from more angles before making any decisions, especially on a community as diverse as SE. Thanks for the compliment on my proposal.

Comment: Thanks for the change -- we've been waiting for this ever since the big un-designing four (4!) years ago https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7846/36296 - the light green looked horrible on all sites which use red as primary colour

Comment: I don't have a particular axe to grind on the color front, but have to chime in: announcing network-wide things on meta.SO is *maddening*. Can we get some **"SO =/= SE"** swag made and shipped to every employee?

Comment: Why you announce cross site changes on a specific site? We have a meta site for the whole network, which is, well, this one. I know that SO is special, but still, would love to know about changes to the network without having to check other meta sites.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Actually WCAG compliance _is_ a meaningful goal, and is required by _law_ in some countries. While WCAG compliance not explicitly required in the US (except for federal agencies, who must adhere to WCAG 2.0+), where the network is hosted and the company is based, the ADA _has_ been held by courts and the federal government to apply to websites, and pretty much any organization with a website that gets sued for being inaccessible loses their case and has to update their website, and WCAG is really _the_ only standard (it's certainly the one that the US gov't and courts recommend).

Comment: @TylerH The goal you describe is "not get sued", and "WCAG" is a way to achieve it. IANAL, so I don't know if failing to conform to it on *any* color themes or *all* themes can get SE in trouble.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat 'not getting sued' is an aspiration, not a goal. It is not really specific or measurable, which a _goal_ needs to be. In business, goals are things you can actively and realistically achieve through action (see the SMART acronym -- literally part of business 101 classes in school). Achieving WCAG 2.0 compliance is a goal; It is specific and measurable and something the company has direct control over.

Comment: *"why not hide accesibility features"* @HolyBlackCat There is absolutely no good reason to *hide* accessibility features or have inaccessible themes. People with disabilities should not have to hunt for settings to make a site usable (how would new users even know these settings exist?).

Comment: @TylerH I'm not a native speaker, so maybe that wasn't the best word. My point is, WCAG compliance is not an end in itself, you don't do it just because you feel like it.

Comment: @BSMP Making the site look good for people with good eyesight isn't a good reason anymore??

Comment: @HolyBlackCat It's not a good reason to make the site inaccessible, no. Making the site look good does not require making it inaccessible.

Comment: @BSMP Tell this to the SE designers. :( I'm half-joking of course, I'm getting used to the new green color, but still.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat And _my_ point is that yes, it _is_ an end unto itself. And no, it is not just because "they feel like it". It is because WCAG guidelines are intended to make the site usable by more people (and, in part, to help prevent legal action for lack of compliance, as it happens).