# Watched question titles are changed to blue on themed sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, tag-watching

The site's theme colors were preserved for unwatched questions, but watched questions have been forced blue, as seen on https://rpg.stackexchange.com:

[image]

The site's theme colors should be preserved. The issue is particularly bad on [Christianity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/), where the site's theme blue and the new blue are slightly off:

[image]

Comment: Related: [Why has the green accepted answer indicator become darker on all the meta sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/381858/335251) – Presumably those changes are the cause of this issue.

Comment: Looks [awful on SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/381873/158281) as well. Makes me think every watched tag link is one I've visited

Comment: Related: [it's broken on non-themed sites (Stack Overflow) too](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/420272/208273), at least in dark mode.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This issue was caused by a non-theme color being set on watched post summary titles in a recent design system change. We've reverted that change and shipped the reversion. Thanks for the report!