# Please test design / colour changes in dark mode and site themes

Tags: discussion, design, accessibility, dark-mode

It's become painfully obvious that design changes, especially around colours, are never tested in **Dark Mode**, at least not for https://stackoverflow.com.

These changes [affect other themed sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/381863/158281) as well, so please consider that before voting to close this as off-topic for MSE.

I've [noted this before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/418888/283366) and even [received a response](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418851/updated-button-styling-for-vote-arrows-a-b-testing-has-concluded/418888#comment916661_418888) from the Director of Product Design, [@Piper](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/355481/piper)

> Thank you for bringing this to our attention. You are correct—reviewing the designs in dark mode doesn't happen enough. I completely agree that this (both the design solution in dark mode and lack of process in dark mode testing) is not okay. I will work immediately on a solution for the arrows in dark mode and I will also work to make sure dark mode testing is added to our process is a more formalized manner.

But this just isn't happening.

So please, *pretty please*, test the changes you make on the sites where they will be applied in whatever modes are available on those sites.

---

Some less-than-stellar examples from the past include the ill-fated, eye-watering *watched* tag:

[image: watched tag]

The contrast deficient vote arrow circles:

[image: vote arrow circles]

The *blue-trending-to-white* text colour for watched and visited questions which is tricking me into thinking I've visited everything already:

[image: question text colour]

*This one happens every single time there's a change to colours!*

And most recently, a slew of dark-mode related issues with the [New colors launched](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/393939/158281)

Comment: Since dark mode doesn't exist in MSE or other SE sites (excluding SO)... I feel your question could be asked in MSO instead.

Comment: @RandomPerson but design changes come from the MSE team and are applied to SO. All I'm requesting is that they are tested properly

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by "MSE team". I think the Design department of the company takes care of design stuff for both SO and SE sites.

Comment: @RandomPerson design changes are announced here and developed by team members of Stack Exchange. The changes effect all SE sites. It's not only SO affected (see [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/381863/158281))

Comment: @RandomPerson And isn't that a good reason for this question to be asked here?

Comment: @Joachim Yeah. But isn't dark mode SO-specific?

Comment: @RandomPerson for now it is, but see the end of [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/345762/152859).

Comment: @RandomPerson I've clearly pointed out that design changes made by the SE team effect multiple sites, not just SO. Even the close vote that four people have opted to use says _"Do not use this close reason for questions that relate to multiple sites, even if they focus on a specific site"_

Comment: "design changes are announced here " The latest set of network-wide design changes was only ever announced on MSO, never here. The only way it came here were posts by users from across the network wondering why the colour changed....

Comment: The color for question titles with watched tags has been driving me crazy since yesterday!!!

Comment: I'm 100% in favour of more testing, including dark mode, but honestly: I really don't see why today's change would be so much of a problem. It looks fine to me; that might be because I have macOS' Night Shift on?

Comment: @Glorfindel _"I really don't see why today's change would be so much of a problem"_ Which one are you referring to? The post mentions two new changes and one of them [has already been fixed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/420278/8967612).

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine sorry, I meant the new green color for the answers.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz _"The latest set of network-wide design changes was only ever announced on MSO"_... to which they've now [offered an apology](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382079/158281)